# Java weird method

Tags: java, methods

I am currently trying to learn how to make games in 3D, so I watched a few YouTube-Tutorials. In one [Tutorial](https://github.com/OskarVeerhoek/YouTube-tutorials/blob/master/src/episode_19/MineFront.java) I found this method:

```
int floorTexture = glGenTextures();
{
  // ...
}
```

[Source (Line 215)](https://github.com/OskarVeerhoek/YouTube-tutorials/blob/master/src/episode_19/MineFront.java)

I have never seen this type of method (I think it's a method) before, so I now have two questions:

1. Can I add parameters to this method? This code doesn't work

   ```
   int texture (String texturename) = glGenTextures();
   ```
2. What does the `=glGenTextures()` do?

(I want to load different textures in one method.)

Comment: are you sure it was Java ? because I have never come across something like this in java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a method declaration - it's a method *call* followed by a block.

The block itself is unnecessary, and basically just confusing. Heck, the fact that the `main` method is nearly 500 lines long is a good indication that this *isn't* code you should be taking hints from - at least in terms of structure...

Comment: +1 .. it is strange code ... easy to confused with anomynous methods  like : new abstractClass() { ... }

Comment: @mglauche or with stubs and seams

Comment: +1 for the advice not to take hints from such a code. Much of it indicates, that this is not the best style.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wrote a own method for that now.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a method definition. It's a method **call**. The `{` after the call introduces a new block/scope. If you look immediately above that call, you'll see another block that (because it's by itself) doesn't look like a method definition.

Answer (score 2):

This is a method call followed by a block of code. The block of code has nothing to do with the preceding method call. Its only use is to define a new block scope (allowing to define local variables that are visible only in this block).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the indentation. It's just a definition of an `int` variable `floorTexture` which is initialized to the return value of `glGenTextures()`. The code that follows is just a block within `main` to ensure variables go out of scope after the block is left. So there is no method, and no way to add parameters.